# Merge two CSV files in python iteratively

Tags: python, csv, merge, header

I have a set of data saved across multiple .csv files with a fixed number of columns. Each column corresponds to a different measurement.

I would like to add a header to each file. The header will be identical for all files, and is comprised of three rows. Two of these rows are used to identify their corresponding columns.

I am thinking that I could save the header in a separate .csv file, then iteratively merge it with each data file using a `for` loop.

How can I do this in python? I am new to the language.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can do that easily with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It will be faster and easier than what you're currently thinking which may create problems.

Three simple commands will be used for reading, merging and putting that in a new file and they are:

```
pandas.read_csv()
pandas.merge()
pandas.to_csv()
```

You can read what arguments you have to use and more details about them [here.](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 0):

```
for your case you may need first to create new files with
the headers with them. then you would do another loop to
add the rows, but skipping the header. 

import csv
with open("data_out.csv","a") as fout:
    # first file:
    with open("data.csv") as f: # you header file
        for line in f:
            fout.write(line)

    with open("data_2.csv") as f:
        next(f)        # this will skip first line
        for line in f:
          fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of running a for loop appending two files for multiple files, an easier solution would be to put all the csv files you want to merge into a single folder and feed the path to the program. This will merge all the csv files into a single csv file.
>   (Note: The attributes of each file must be same)

```
import os
import pandas as pd

#give the path to the folder containing the multiple csv files
dirList = os.listdir(path)

#Put all their names into a list
filenames = []
for item in dirList:
    if ".csv" in item:
        filenames.append(item) 

#Create a dataframe and make sure it's empty (not required but safe practice if using for appending)
df1 = pd.Dataframe()
df1.drop(df1.index, inplace=True)

#Convert each file to a dataframe and append it to dataframe df1
for f in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df1 = df1.append(df)

#Convert the dataframe into a single csvfile
df1.to_csv(csvfile, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```